# How to tidy the data set with column containing multiple information-Sample data put?

Tags: r, tidy

Please help me make my data tidy. Thanks.
  The total observations is 394, with 26 columns.  Data is exported from ms excel.
Data sample is given below. In this sample actually there should be only three observations/rows.
In the vectors d1..d2..no and Farmer.Name the observations corresponding to NA of v1 should be cleared and added to the preceding row value.
the d1..d2..no corresponds to three observations (two date observations one unique identification number )and so do the Farmer.Name vector.
The sample is

```
d1..d2..no<-c("27/01/2020", "43832", "KE004421", "43832", "43832", 
              "KE003443", "31/12/2019", "43832", "KE0001512")

Farmer.Name<-c("S Jacob Gender:male","farmer type :marginal","farmer category :general", 
               "J Isac Gender :Female","farmer type: large","farmer category :general",
               "P Kumar Gender :Male","farmer type:small","farmer category :general")

adress<-c("k11",NA,NA,"k12",NA,NA,"k13",NA,NA)

amount<-c(25,NA,NA,25,NA,NA,32,NA,NA)

mydata<-data.frame(v1=v1, d1..d2..no=d1..d2..no, Farmer.Name=Farmer.Name, 
               adress=adress, amount=amount)
```

In the vectors d1..d2..no and Farmer.Name the observations corresponding to NA of v1 should be cleared and added to the preceding row value.
the d1..d2..no corresponds to three observations (two date observations one unique identification number )
and so do the Farmer.Name vector. That is, my result expected is like from this code

```
v1<-c(1,2,3)

d1<-c("27/01/2020","43832","31/12/2019")
d2<-c("43832","43832","43832")
no<-c("KE004421","KE003443","KE0001512")
Farmer.Name1<-c("S Jacob","J Isac","P Kumar")
Gender<-c("male","female","male")
farmer_type <-c("marginal","large","small")
farmer_category <-c("general", "general", "general")
adress<-c("k11","k12","k13")
amount<-c(25,25,32)

myfinaldata<-data.frame(v1=v1,d1=d1,d2=d2,no=no,
                    Farmer.Name1=Farmer.Name1,
                    farmer_type=farmer_type,
                    farmer_category=farmer_category,
                    adress=adress,amount=amount)
```

The result should be

```
  v1         d1    d2        no Farmer.Name1 farmer_type farmer_category adress amount
1  1 27/01/2020 43832  KE004421      S Jacob    marginal         general    k11     25
2  2      43832 43832  KE003443       J Isac       large         general    k12     25
3  3 31/12/2019 43832 KE0001512      P Kumar       small         general    k13     32
```

I am a novice to programming and r, learning through online resources. Also my first post on this platform. Please forgive any mistakes.

I have done a lot of mess with spread,separate, etc of tidy vesre.. But stuck at how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untidy data can be a challenge. Here is a `tidyverse` approach.

First, added proposed column names expected for `d1`, `d2`, and `no`. Assumes rows are in this order.

Column `Farmer.Name` is `separate`d into two columns, by `:`.

The `Name` itself is separated before the word `Gender`.

`fill` allows for common values to be filled in for the same individual (such as `v1`, `adress`, `amount`, and `Name`).

`pivot_wider` is done to spread the data wide, first, by `d1`, `d2`, and `no`, and then by the other columns including `Gender`, `farmer_type`, and `farmer_category`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- mydata %>%
  mutate(d_var = rep(c("d1", "d2", "no"), times = 3)) %>%
  separate(Farmer.Name, into = c("Var", "Val"), sep = ":") %>%
  separate(Var, into = c("Name", "Var"), sep = "(?=Gender)", fill = "left") %>%
  mutate_at(c("Name", "Var"), trimws) %>%
  fill(v1, adress, amount, Name, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(Var = gsub(" ", "_", Var)) 

df1 %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(v1, Name, adress, amount), names_from = d_var, values_from = d1..d2..no) %>%
  left_join(pivot_wider(df1, id_cols = c(v1, Name, adress, amount), names_from = Var, values_from = Val))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 10
     v1 Name    adress amount d1         d2    no        Gender farmer_type farmer_category
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>       <chr>          
1     1 S Jacob k11        25 27/01/2020 43832 KE004421  male   "marginal"  general        
2     2 J Isac  k12        25 43832      43832 KE003443  Female " large"    general        
3     3 P Kumar k13        32 31/12/2019 43832 KE0001512 Male   "small"     general
```

Answer (score 1):

The dates in your data set are not in date format. Consider formatting them after this.

```
library(reshape)

df.new <- cbind(mydata[seq(1, nrow(mydata), 3), ], mydata[seq(2, nrow(mydata), 3), ][2:3], mydata[seq(3, nrow(mydata), 3), ][2:3])
colnames(df.new) <- c("v1", "d1", "Farmer.Name1", "adress", "amount", "d2", "farmer_type", "no", "farmer_category")
df.new <- df.new[c(1,2,6, 8,3, 7,9, 4,5)]


library(stringr)
df.new$Farmer.Name1 <- word(df.new$Farmer.Name1,1,sep = "\\ Gender")
df.new$farmer_type <- word(df.new$farmer_type,2,sep = "\\:")
df.new$farmer_category <- word(df.new$farmer_category,2,sep = "\\:")
```

Final table:

```
> df.new
  v1         d1    d2        no Farmer.Name1 farmer_type farmer_category adress amount
1  1 27/01/2020 43832  KE004421      S Jacob    marginal         general    k11     25
4  2      43832 43832  KE003443       J Isac       large         general    k12     25
7  3 31/12/2019 43832 KE0001512      P Kumar       small         general    k13     32
```

P.S.: I have not renamed the row numbers.